# MongoDB - Count does not match number of documents

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a function that moves documents from collection_one to collection_two. I have run into an odd error where the counts don't add up.

> collection_one.count({}) return 3.3 mil records

After moving all the documents, `collection_two.count({})` return 3.2 mil.

Each document in `collection_one` contains a unique uuid `run_id`. When I run the following commands, these are the outputs:

> collection_one.count({'run_id': { $eq : 'uuid'}}), I get 3.2 mil
>   collection_one.count({'run_id': { $ne : 'uuid'}}),  I get 0;

Basically, there are 0.1 mil missing records, which only show up in the empty count.
I have tried moving the documents in a couple of different ways via pymongo and using copyTo() in the shell.

```
for doc in source.find():
    try:
        target.insert(doc)
    except:
        print('Did not copy')
```

and a batch move function

```
for n in range(0, ceil_num_of_batches):
    result = source.find(data_filter).limit(batch_size).skip(n*batch_size)
    insert_queries = [InsertOne(doc) for doc in result]
    try:
        target.bulk_write(insert_queries)
    except BulkWriteError as bwe:
        logger.error(bwe.details)
```

Both of these produce the same error. copyTo() however copies all 3.3 mil but has been deprecated.
Collection_two has a unique index but collection_one doesn't.

Comment: Can you paste your code that you're running to copy the documents? Do you have any unique indexes setup on collection_two?

Comment: @RobertSeaman I've added the information to the main post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [countDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/)ocuments to get an accurate document count. Count uses internal metadata and may not always give an accurate result.

Comment: I am using Mongo version 4.0.5 but countDocuments is not a recognised function for whatever reason. I used the aggregate operation in the documentation you linked and that seems to have solved the issue. Many thanks.